# My .vim folder is empty

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I have been using Ubuntu for a little while. I started learning programming recently. I started using vim. I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed. I do not know when I installed vim. I am wondering if it was present by default.

I have no ~/.vimrc file and the ~/.vim folder is empty. I found that .vimrc file should just be created by me.

1)All vim files seem to be located in /usr/share/vim. Why was ~/.vim created and left empty?

2)To configure and customize vim should they be shifted to ~/.vim? If so, can you point me to a resource which helps me do that?

Comment: Configuring vim for the first time can be a somewhat daunting task.  Looking just now I just found a [sensible defaults plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible) by tpope (who is essentially a vim plugins rockstar).  [This tool to generate a sane config](http://vimconfig.com/) also looks helpful.  Once you get a basic config going, it can be fun and useful to browse github for other programmers' vim configs, which they often source control, and you can poach for settings and useful plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vim` stuff in your home directory is specifically for *your* customisations, rather than system-wide ones.

That's the way it generally works under UNIXy operating systems, global stuff affecting everyone is found in a global area (such as `/etc`) and user-specific stuff is found in the user's home directory somewhere.

If you look at the man page for vim, you'll see something like:

```
/usr/share/vim/vimrc   System wide Vim initializations.
~/.vimrc               Your personal Vim initializations.
/usr/share/vim/gvimrc  System wide gvim initializations.
~/.gvimrc              Your personal gvim initializations.
```

The `.vim` directory in your home directory is specifically for things like plug-ins that only you want, rather than inflicting them on everyone. On a home machine with just one user, it doesn't make a lot of difference (unless you want the plug-ins available when you `sudo` to `root` as well).

But on a system with many users (and where you may not have the power to affect global areas), you'll need to do customisation only for your user.

Answer (score 1):

Do not change anything under `/usr/share/vim` this will be updated when ever vim gets updated so your changes will be lost. Do not move them to `~/.vim` as they are loaded automatically.

If you want to customize vim yourself you can place files in `~/.vim`. This folder is part of the default vim runtimepath.

The different folders that you can add in `~/.vim` that allow customization are below (Taken from `:help runtimepath`)

```
This is a list of directories which will be searched for runtime
files:
  filetype.vim  filetypes by file name |new-filetype|
  scripts.vim   filetypes by file contents |new-filetype-scripts|
  autoload/ automatically loaded scripts |autoload-functions|
  colors/   color scheme files |:colorscheme|
  compiler/ compiler files |:compiler|
  doc/      documentation |write-local-help|
  ftplugin/ filetype plugins |write-filetype-plugin|
  indent/   indent scripts |indent-expression|
  keymap/   key mapping files |mbyte-keymap|
  lang/     menu translations |:menutrans|
  menu.vim  GUI menus |menu.vim|
  plugin/   plugin scripts |write-plugin|
  print/    files for printing |postscript-print-encoding|
  spell/    spell checking files |spell|
  syntax/   syntax files |mysyntaxfile|
  tutor/    files for vimtutor |tutor|
```

If you want a more detailed explanation of what these directories do (and what should go in them) you can read about them in `:help`. The help in vim is very detailed and will explain almost everything about vim.

If nothing is in your `~/.vim` directory don't worry. Your distribution might of added it to simplify your life since some people get confused when it doesn't exist.